# How can I untar multiple tar files over ssh?

Tags: bash, ssh, tar

I am attempting to untar multiple tar files over ssh:

```
ssh user@hostname "cat /dir/file*.tgz" | tar xvzf -
```

The above only works on the first file match on the remote server. The local (dest) server only receives one file. The wildcard has been verified to match multiple files though.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: This is not an SSH problem per se; you'd see the same behaviour even if you were working locally (i.e. `cat /dir/file*.tgz | tar xvzf -`).

Comment: Thanks Oli, helpful point for sure. You know another way?

Comment: Could you just use SCP instead of SSH?

Comment: Yes, I can scp then extract. Just looking for the most succinct method, scp is my fallback. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Edit after first try didn't work:)

Another idea, avoiding multiple `ssh` calls and also `scp` (since this needs at least one roundtrip between each file):

```
ssh user@hostname 'tar cf - /dir/file*.tgz' | tar xf - --to-command='tar xzvf -'
```

We use one more `tar` call on the server side to wrap all the files together, a second `tar` call on the client side to unwrap them again, which will then be calling `tar xzv` for each entry once. This works similar to the base64-answer from *sehe*, but will be more efficient since it does not blow up the files.

Comment: well, no; there is GNU `tar --catenate -f existing.tar appendix*.tar` BUT (a) it cannot do streaming (b) it cannot handle compressed archives

Comment: Yeah, I do not want to append multiple archives into one, but simply extract the contents of multiple archives, which come in the input as one stream. I got a better idea, editing now.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. You are all unix scholars and this is by far the most interesting of questions I've seen in a good while.

Comment: Ah, it is mainly a combinition of basic knowledge how unix work (e.g. what is a pipe), combined with reading the manual page of `tar`. But I'm glad we could help.

Answer (score 2):

```
mkdir /tmp/tars
scp 'user@hostname:/dir/file*.tgz' /tmp/tars/
foreach tarname in /tmp/tars/*.tgz; do tar xzvf "$tarname"; done
```

If you absolutely cannot store temp copies:

```
ssh user@hostname 'ls /dir/file*.tgz' | while read tarname; 
do
    ssh user@hostname "cat '/dir/$tarname'" | tar xzvf -
done
```

Comment: made it slightl more succinct (regarding temp storage)

Comment: haha, tried the while loop but only the first of the returned ls files is extracted. Ran the ls part by itself and verified multiple files are returned. Changing to a for loop worked though. Something about how the lines were piped to while I suppose.

Comment: Well, dare I ask? are you positive that the other archives are (a) valid (b) nonempty...

Comment: Hmm, this needs multiple `ssh` connections.

Comment: You may need `ls -1` here for listing the files each on a new line. Otherwise `read` will read multiple files at once.

Comment: @Paulo: Really?  On what system does `ls` output multiple columns when stdout is not a TTY?

Comment: @Paolo: what John said; On the multiple ssh connections: well doh! I like to [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and just use ssh -M to multiplex connections :) This clearly has the benefit that it is trivial to run extracts in parallel in case you are not bandwidth limited

Comment: @John: good point. I just tried to find an explanation for CarpeNoctem's observation.

Comment: @sehe: SSH multiplexing is a good idea here. How about showing an example of this, too?

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap this in a find call and then use the exec switch to iterate over each found file.

```
ssh user@hostname 'find /path/to/dir -name "*.tar.gz" -exec tar xvf "{}" ";"'
```

Single ssh call, no need to write bash script.

Answer (score 0):

CarpeNoctem inspired me to go even further and provide a one-stop solution that require only a single ssh connection and does all the stuff streaming.

A tested proof concept (oneline formatted for readability):

```
 (echo '#!/bin/sh'; 
  for a in /dir/file*.tgz
  do 
      echo 'base64 -d <<"TARIMAGE" | tar xvzf -'
      base64 "$a"
      echo "TARIMAGE"
  done) | ssh -C remote 'cd /targetdir && sh -'
```

Of course you'd actually want to reverse the roles of local and remote, in which case I'd recommend getting the script generation into a shell script instead:

<sup>gen_script.sh, chmod +x</sup>

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '#!/bin/sh'; 
for a in /dir/file*.tgz
do 
    echo 'base64 -d <<"TARIMAGE" | tar xvzf -'
    base64 "$a"
    echo "TARIMAGE"
done
```

<sup>invocation</sup>

```
scp gen_script.sh user@hostname:
ssh -C user@hostname /home/user/gen_script.sh | (cd targetdir && sh -)
```

#### Loose ends, thoughts:

- you can use uuencode, od, xxd, pgp or whatnot instead of base64
- you can enable compression on ssh (ssh -C) to further optimize bandwidth
- I made the targetdir/ step up myself to prevent accidents; you can let it off if you don't need it :)

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to work with files than with commands. So rather than use the `ssh` command to access remote hosts, and the `tar` command to access archives, use the [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) filesystem to access files on remote hosts

```
mkdir hostname-dir.tmp
sshfs user@hostname:/dir hostname-dir.tmp
for a in hostname-dir.tmp/*.tgz; do tar xvf "$a"; done
fusermount -u hostname-dir.tmp
```

You can even go one step further and the [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/) to access archives as directories¹. All brought to you by [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/), a generic framework to access all kinds of things as files.

```
mountavfs
mkdir hostname-dir.tmp
sshfs user@hostname:/dir hostname-dir.tmp
for a in ~/.avfs$PWD/hostname-dir.tmp/*.tgz; do cp -Rp "$a#"/* .; done
fusermount -u hostname-dir.tmp
```

If your shell is zsh, that `for` loop can be replaced by a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers).

```
cp -Rp ~/.avfs$PWD/hostname-dir.tmp/*.tgz(e\''reply=($REPLY\#/*)'\') .
```

¹  <sub>AVFS can also access remote files over SSH, but I don't think you can access remote archives that way: AVFS paths only have a single hop. So SSHFS is still necessary.</sub>